# Unable to knit html in Rmarkdown with vcf2geno

Tags: r, r-markdown, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to knit a perfectly functioning Rmarkdown file to html in Rstudio but am running into this error when pressing the "Knit" command. My code up until the error. Any help would be appreciated - Thanks!

```
library("plotly")
library("devtools")
library("tidyverse")
# devtools::install_github("bcm-uga/LEA")
library("LEA")
library("ggplot2")
library("factoextra")
library("FactoMineR")
library("corrplot")
library("plotly")
library("tess3r")
library("mapplots")
library("devtools")
library("sf")
library("adegenet")
library("vcfR")
library("poppr")
library("reshape2")
library("ggsn")
library("raster")
library("rgeos")
library("maps")
library("maptools")
library("grid")
library("miscTools")
library("stringr")
library("ggpubr")
library("ggplot2")
library("rgdal")
library("rgeos")
library("maptools")
library("grid")
library("gridExtra")
library("maps")
```

```
setwd("C:/Users/jc486631/OneDrive - James Cook University/Melbourne/Melbourne/Analysis/LEA/TSI/July 2020 vcf (n=22)")
```

```
vcf2geno(input.file = "tsi_only2018.vcf", "tsi_only2018.admix.geno", force = T)
```

"Error in vcf2geno(input_file, "tsi_only2018.admix.geno", force = T) : internal error in trio library calls: < Anonymous > ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> vcf2geno In addition: There were 28 warnings".